# Why is this python operation returning a tuple?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

a = date.today() - timedelta(1)
# a above is a tuple and not datetime
# Since I am a C programmer, I would expect python to cast back to datetime
# but it is casting it to a tuple
```

Can you please tell me why this is happening? and also how I can see that the operation above results in a datetime?

I am a python newbie, sorry if this is a trivial thing, but I am stuck here for a while!

Thanks

Comment: do a print type(a). It shouldn't be a string.

Comment: I don't see how you get a tuple out of that. Executing that code yields a datetime.date object in a.

Comment: I am getting a string. I am serious!

>>> a = date.today() - timedelta(1)
>>> print a
2010-10-07

Comment: Sure. But that doesn't mean `a` really *is* a string. datetime.date just provides special behaviour to be printed that way. If you want to know the type of a, use the built-in type function.

Comment: Here is some proof http://i.imgur.com/mYjLH.png

Comment: ok, when I check the type, it is datetime, but, when I compare it with another datetime variable, I get an error. Let me debug a little bit and get back.. now that this syntax is fine, I will check the other parts. Thanks!

Comment: Completely unrelated, but helpful: Get IPython. It's a much improved shell for Python.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the repr of a confuses you:

```
>>> a
datetime.date(2010, 10, 8)
```

this is not a tuple, it's what datetime uses as repr(). Print it to get its string() representation:

```
>>> print a
2010-10-08
```

Either str() a yourself explicitly or use a.strftime() to do you own formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Having looked at your image: [image: Python code screenshot]

I think you are assuming it's a string, because `print` outputs a string - but that's exactly what its job is! The object *is* a `datetime`. You cannot convert it to a `date` by passing it to the `date()` constructor, either - instead you should call `a.date()`

Comment: I have no idea where the -2 came from. Anyone care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

use `type` built-in function:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> 
>>> a = date.today() - timedelta(1)
>>> a
datetime.date(2010, 10, 8)
>>> type(a)
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
date.today() - timedelta(1)
```

returns a [date](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.date) object.

This object have two string representations:

- The most common readable format is by calling `str()` function (the same called using print), in this case `str(a)` gives you `'2010-10-08'`
- A second representation, the object nature, is by using `repr()` function. In this case `repr(a)` returns `'datetime.date(2010, 10, 8)'`.